# sending a serialized list larger than 2048 bytes over a socket

Tags: python, json, sockets

hi folks i would like to know how can i send a serialized list that its size is greater than 2048 bytes over a socket i noticed if i send something greater i get the following error on the server side:
 Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 2045 (char 2045)

client side:

```
list = ['111111','222222'.......] list has over 4k elements maybe more 

 data = json.dumps({"elements":list})
 s = socket.socket()
 s.connect((127.0.0.1,1234))
 s.send(data)
 s.close()
```

Server side:

```
 s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 host = "127.0.0.1"
 port1 = 1234
 s.bind(('',port1))
 s.listen(5)
 c,addr_bot = s.accept()


 dataRecv = json.loads(c.recv(2048)
 for key,value in dataRecv.items:
   if key == 'elements':
     print key
```

thank you very much and look forward your help

here is an example of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two issue:

- `s.send(data)` may send less than `len(data)` bytes, use `s.sendall(data.encode())` instead
- `c.recv(2048)` may receive no more than 2048 bytes, you could use `c.makefile()` and pass it to `json.load()` instead, to read the whole response:

  ```
  import json
  from contextlib import closing

  # open server socket ...
  while True:
      conn, _ = s.accept()
      with closing(conn), closing(conn.makefile()) as file:
          data = json.load(file)
      print(len(data['elements']))
  ```

Comment: @PuN1sh3r: if you think it answers your question then you could [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) so that others could see that you've found the solution (the accepted answer is sorted to be at the top). Note: it is not a request to accept the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sockets are streams of characters (so a sequence of characters and TCP handles splitting it apart, sending it, resending missed bits and putting all the packets back together).

What you put in is what you get out *BUT* you lose any 'breaks' in the data to separate between what you write in (ie, s.send("hello") and then s.send("world") arrives as "helloworld" or maybe "hello" then "world" or maybe "he" "ll" "ow" "or" "ld").

As Ramchandra Apte said, when the socket closes you get nothing more out of it.

Usually it is a good idea to add your own 'wrapper' around the data you are sending, such as:

```
s.send( "s%s:"%(len(data)) )
s.send(data)
```

then on the other end, look for 's1234:' and then read the next 1234 characters to get your data.

Or if you know there are no null characters in your stream, you could:

```
s.send(data)
s.send('\0')
```

then keep reading from the socket until you get a '\0' and you know that is the break between messages.

Just be aware that if you send two messages you might read them on the other end as "hello world\0hello mars\0" and you'd have to split it and deal with that yourself.

Or worse you might read "hello world\0hello" and you have to keep the partial second message for the rest of it. :-)

Ah sockets..... <3

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are `c.recv(2048)`; only 2048 bytes are being read. You need to add a while loop and keep receiving data until `""` is returned which means the client socket has been closed. Also, close the socket in the client code using `s.close()` after sending. If you will be sending multiple messages with a time gap (maybe as data arrives you will be sending them to the server) use a class which knows how long the message will. The problem with simply recv'ing unlimited amounts of data is that it will keep waiting until some data arrives or the connection is closed. Also, it is impossible to distinguish each message from the other, as noted in [Cameron Blackwood's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23178737/443348). So if there is a time gap, your server will freeze until it receives the data. So you should include the size of the message when sending it. Thus recv will only recv exactly the number of bytes required and it won't wait unnecessarily. An implementation of this can be found in the [Python Socket Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#using-a-socket)